# Determinism in Verilog: event controls

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

Consider the below example:

```
module test;
  reg a;
  initial begin
    a = 1'b1;
  end
  initial begin
    wait(a) $display("wait(a): %b", a);
    $display("wait(a)");
  end
  initial begin
    @a $display("@a: %b", a);
    $display("@a");
  end
endmodule
```

When I run it, I *always* get this output:

```
wait(a): 1
wait(a)
```

Which confuses me. My understanding of the code is like this:

1. the default value for `a` is `x`.
2. all initial blocks start in parallel at time 0.
3. the first initial block does a block assignment while at the same time the `wait` and `@a` event controls read `a`.
4. since there is no determinism in the sequencing among the three, the blocking assignment `a=1'b1`, may be executed before or after the `wait(a)` or `@a`.
5. if the blocking assignment is executed before `wait(a)` and `@a`, no output should be displayed since `wait(a)` and `@a` will not detect any change in `a`.
6. if, however, the blocking assignment `a=1'b1` is executed after the read of `a` in `wait(a)` and `@a`, which both will read as `x`, then the output from both should be displayed after the blocking assignment completes.

But, as I pointed out above, the output I see is always the output from `wait(a)`. Can someone please explain to me:

1. What is going on and the defect in my understanding?

And more generally, and outside of the example above:

2. What exactly happens when the simulator encounters a `wait(a)` and `@a`?
3. `wait(a)` and `@a` detect level and edge changes (in the example, level and edge change are identical). When we say "change" in this case, does it mean a change after the last read of the variables involved in the event controls (in this example `a`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct up until point 5.

If `a=1'b1` gets executed before the `wait(a)`, then it has no effect—it does not suspend the process. If the reverse order, the `wait(a)` suspends the process and resumes after the assignment `a=1'b1`. In your example, you always see the output from the second `initial` block regardless of the order.

But the ordering is very important for the third `initial` block. The `@a` must execute before any change to `a`, otherwise it suspends until it sees another change. Although you should not rely on it, most tools executed initial blocks in source code order. But optimizations and ordering between `initial` blocks in different modules can never guarantee ordering.